# How can I make my WordPress slug a strings data?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently gathering data from the SoundCloud API for my WordPress site, and I'm trying to set the permalink portion from the SoundCloud API as the slug in my WordPress site.

---

Here's some of my code which gathers the permalink (*not sure why you would need this but I am sure I'll get some heat if I don't have ANY code here*.)

```
$client_ID = 'xxxx'; 
$profilename = $_GET['pr'];

$sc = curl_init();
curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/'.$user_ID.'/tracks?client_id='. $client_ID.'');
curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($sc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($sc);
curl_close($sc);
$content = json_decode($output, true);
print $content[0]['permalink'];

/* not really important so commented out.

    print '<pre>';
    print_r($content);
    print '</pre>'; 

*/
```

The above code obviously returns all of the data for the tracks we have relating to the artist set within the `pr` variable.

---

If you look at the example above, I have printed out the `permalink`, in this case it reads as this `stop-the-car-w-horsehead-prod-smokeasac`. So I would like for my website's url to look like this. http://www.example.com/track/stop-the-car-w-horsehead-prod-smokeasac instead of the default **WordPress** slug.

Comment: `print "http://www.example.com/track/".$content[0]['permalink'];`

Comment: @Anant not what I am looking for, I want the actual slug of my website to be that url appose to the standard `?p=4918` variable. But only within the `track` category as my example displays.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/is-it-possible-to-get-a-page-link-from-its-slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have to override the default handler for the slugs. If I understand you correctly, you want to have dynamic links to point to a specific page. If you don't want to create each url in the database, you have to take a look at which file takes care of redirecting and maybe make a corehack to parse the result of your curl request to Soundcloud...

Hope this helps.